# Obfuscating an .exe file

Tags: antivirus, obfuscation

Is there a way to obfuscate an existing .exe file?

I'm in a situation where I cannot transfer the `winPEAS.exe` file (for PrivEsc purposes) on a Win10 machine because of the AV blocking the executable.

Any other solution will be appreciated.

Comment: What about encrypt the file and decrypt on the destination host?

Comment: Zip or otherwise compress the file.

Comment: @camp0 Not so easy, AV detects it

Answer (score 1):

There are readily made obfuscated winPEAS executables released by Carlos Polop.

Also, you can try in-memory execution of winPEAS batch via PowerShell. This way, you will not be writing winPEAS to the disk. There might be a chance AV does not detect it

If all else fails, perhaps you might want to read into what winPEAS does and perform manual enumerations yourself.